# PHP form ouput to an RTF document

Tags: php, forms, rtf

We have a paper form that clients fill out. The boss wanted this form to be available online and automatically fill out the paper form which is in an .rtf format.

In the rtf document I have created fields where input is suppose to be added. For example the Company name looks like this. Company Name: [CN]. I have it to where the php form will add the information to the rtf document, but I can't get it to add all the information. It will only add the Company Name. Here is the code I have tried so far.

```
$doc = file_get_contents('ca.rtf');
$info = str_replace('[CN]', $_POST['compName'], $doc);
$info .= str_replace('[SA]', $_POST['address'], $doc);
$info .= str_replace('[CT]', $_POST['city'], $doc);
$info .= str_replace('[ST]', $_POST['state'], $doc);
$info .= str_replace('[ZP]', $_POST['zip'], $doc);

file_put_contents($_POST['compName'].'.rtf', $info);
```

Comment: You keep running the replace on the original string and then concatenating the result

Comment: and the result of what you tried was ?

Comment: The result of the above code is it will only add the Company Name. How would I be able to update all the fields without using the .=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$doc = file_get_contents('ca.rtf');
$doc = str_replace('[CN]', $_POST['compName'], $doc);
$doc = str_replace('[SA]', $_POST['address'], $doc);
$doc = str_replace('[CT]', $_POST['city'], $doc);
$doc = str_replace('[ST]', $_POST['state'], $doc);
$doc = str_replace('[ZP]', $_POST['zip'], $doc);

file_put_contents($_POST['compName'].'.rtf', $doc);
```

Lets slim it down a little

```
$searchArray = array('[CN]','[SA]','[CT]','[ST]','[ZP]');
$replaceArray = array($_POST['compName'],$_POST['address'],$_POST['city'],$_POST['state'],$_POST['zip']);

$doc = file_get_contents('ca.rtf');
$doc = str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $doc);

file_put_contents($_POST['compName'].'.rtf', $doc);
```